# How to get client id of user assigned identity in an ARM template?

Tags: azure, templates, identity, azure-resource-manager, clientid

Pulling hair out trying to get a user-assigned identity's ClientID in an azure ARM template.

I use this line which works for **other properties** but not clientid.

`"USER_ASSIGNED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID": "[reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full').clientId]"`

I thought using 'full', client id, would be available. Client ID is listed on the portal page at the top but not in the properties list :(

This is for user-assigned not system assigned identities.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This works,

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('IdentityName'))).clientId]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the system assigned identity principal Id, you can just use the `reference` like this:

```
reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full').identity.principalId
```

The system assigned identity is not an individual resource, so it shows the principal Id directly in the identity. But the user-assigned identity is a resource existing in Azure, so it shows in the identity like this:

[image]

Maybe it's more appropriate if you get the resource identity and show its client Id.

**Update**:

You can get all the user-assigned identity properties:

```
reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full').identity.userAssignedIdentities
```

But when you need to get the client id of it, you need to use the resource id as the property name. I think you have no way to do it in the template.

Comment: Are you saying that in the reference function I should use the ResourceID instead of the resource name as shown here. ```reference(resourceName or resourceIdentifier, [apiVersion], ['Full'])```

Comment: @WiredLessInTX I don't mean it. I mean the reference is right to get the information, but you need to get the property of the information and the property depends on the user-assigned identity. It's a resource in Azure. Just like the screenshot shows in the answer. It's difficult to get the property of the `userAssignedIdentities`.

Comment: When looking at the available properties for the user identity itself it doesn’t have a client I’d getter. Unless you show me what the line would look like, I don’t see how your answer helps. But thanks for trying!

Comment: @WiredLessInTX It does not help? You want to get the client id of the user-assigned identity and I have shown you how does it look like in the properties.

Comment: ClientID isn’t in the property list

Comment: @WiredLessInTX So what is the client id do you mean? As I know, the client id is the user-assigned identity property.

Comment: If you put this into the output of the template: ```reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full')``` what properties are returned in the object?

Comment: @bmoore-msft The property of the user-assigned identity.

Comment: Was asking the OP - that should return the clientId property and it was mentioned above that it's not there.

Comment: @bmoore-msft If you use the user-assigned identity resource Id as the IdentityName, then you can change the function into reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full').properties.clientId`.

Comment: I know how this works (I work on the ARM Team) - I'm trying to see if the OP is unblocked.

Comment: @bmoore-msft OK, what I can do is giving the right way, but I can do nothing if the customer cannot understand it or won't try it.

Comment: @CharlesXu  "identity": "[reference(variables('IdentityName'), '2018-11-30', 'full').properties.clientId]" is this correct ?